# Geometric meaning of killing spinor?

Tags: differential-geometry, supersymmetry, spinors, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I know about killing vectors- They forms the basis for the isometries of a metric space.

I am not clear about the definition of killing spinors, in the sense the one there is for killing vectors, which i understand. If someone could explain it to me or suggest some reference which illustrates it in some detail, That would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to know here. The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_spinor) of a Killing spinor is easily found. What is the question?

Comment: On a manifold, covariant derivative of a spinor is given by the expression :  $ D_{\mu}\psi =\del_{\mu}\psi + .5*\Omega_{\mu}^{a,b}*\gamma_{a,b}*\psi $ .                                                                                                                So if the spinor is a killing spinor first term on the right hand side is zero. Please tell me if i am wrong here.

Comment: If i am correct, then this tells me that it does not explicitly depend on its position on the manifold.

Comment: I am studying supersymmetry on curved manifolds, A supersymmetric transformation parameter does not depend on the coordinates of the        manifold. By looking at the expression written in my previous comment, this spinor parameter satisfies the definition of a killing spinor mentioned on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_spinor).

Comment: @ACuriousMind...

Comment: Please *edit* your clarifications into your question

Comment: @ACuriousMind I was asking for a geometric interpretation of a killing spinor, like the one, we have for a killing vector as i have mentioned in the question.